# placing specific number randomly in array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

how to do this?

i want to place a specific number, like number 2 randomly into a `3x3` of zeros `array`,
it did came out, but the coding still not right and somehow number 1 also appear.

```
rows = 3;
cols = 3;

M = zeros(rows,cols);

p = randi(2);

rV = randperm(rows);
cV = randperm(cols);


M(rV(2),cV(2))=p
```

where did i do wrong? any suggestion

Comment: `M(randi(numel(M)))=2` ?

Comment: thanx! that works too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `randi` together with linear indexing

```
m = zeros(3);
m(randi(numel(m))) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need - I've already solved it!

```
a=[2];
m=zeros(3);
m(randperm(numel(m),numel(a)))=a
```